# How to map i and i+1 values of a javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, jsx

I would like to use a map to display the ith value and the i+1th value inside a javascript map to display a set of two cards inside a carousel.

The following is the code I am using, which I would like to modify to get the desired result:

```
{testimonialContent.map((testimonial, i) => {
  return (
    <Carousel.Item className={classes.carousel_item}>
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <div className={classes.testimonial_card}>
          {testimonial[i]}
        </div>
        {/* Second card */}
        <div className={classes.second_card}>
          {testimonial[i+1]}
        </div>
      </div>
    </Carousel.Item>
```

Any help or suggestion is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your code block has unclosed parentheses and braces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` to combine data.

**NOTE:** `(index % 2 === 0)` is where you specify your `nth` child (eg: 2 *in this case*)

Later in your `render` method use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) in `map()`.

```js
const sampleData = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth']

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log("rendered");
    
    const edited = [].concat(sampleData).reduce((unique, value, index) => {
      if (index % 2 === 0) {
        return [...unique, [value]];
      }
      unique[unique.length - 1].push(value);
      return unique;
    }, [])
    
    return (
      <div>
        {edited.map(([item1, item2]) => 
          <div className='block'>
            {item1 && <div className='odd'>{item1}</div>}
            {item2 && <div className='even'>{item2}</div>}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.block {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.odd {
  color: red;
}

.even {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I want to display both the ith and the i+1th value. This display's only one item at a time. I want two elements to be displayed at the same time.

Comment: @anup i updated. Is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

`testimonial` is not an array, but the current iterated item in that array. For the "next" item you can use the array `testimonialContent`.

From the comment I learn that you want to actually produce n/2 rows, so that each item only occurs once. In that case using a plain `.map()` is not good as it will generate as many rows, and you only need half that number of rows. Instead, you could generate an array with half the number of rows (rounded upwards) with `Array.from` and use the callback argument of that method.

```
Array.from({length: (testimonialContent.length+1)>>1}, (_, i) => {
  return (
    <Carousel.Item className={classes.carousel_item}>
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <div className={classes.testimonial_card}>
          {testimonialContent[i*2]}
        </div>
        {/* Second card */}
        <div className={classes.second_card}>
          {testimonialContent[i*2+1] || ""}
        </div>
      </div>
    </Carousel.Item>
  )
})
```

Comment: I like your solution it works but there is a problem I get A and B in one carousel item and B and C in another carousel item. I would like it to be A and B in one carousel item and C and D in another carousel item and so on. Thank you for the solution.

Comment: It would be good if you would add this information to your question. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

## use the entire array not the current iteration

Testimonial in each iteration of the map is a single object. Whereas `testimonialContent` is the entire array.

```
{testimonialContent.map((testimonial, i) => {
  return (
    <Carousel.Item className={classes.carousel_item}>
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <div className={classes.testimonial_card}>
          {testimonial[i]}
        </div>
        {/* Second card */}
        <div className={classes.second_card}>
          {testimonialContent[i+1]} // this is the line to change
        </div>
      </div>
    </Carousel.Item>
```

But something feels very off here. I think you might have an [x y problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Why would you want to use the next iteration as the current iteration? The last item will fail because it doesn't exist and the value of the first `testimonialContent` will never be shown because you're always starting from index 1.

I would rethink what you're doing here and maybe take another approach.

Comment: shouldn't `testimonial[i]` just be `testimonial`?

Comment: @Kobe the author asked for the next testimonial from his code, its an exact copy using the correct array

Comment: Im talking about the first mention of testimonial? `tesitmonial[i]` will be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the `testimonial` instance in your first div and to the element on the i-th +1 palce in your testimonialContent array in your seccond div.

```
{testimonialContent.map((testimonial, i) => {
  return (
    <Carousel.Item className={classes.carousel_item}>
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <div className={classes.testimonial_card}>
          {testimonial}
        </div>
        {/* Second card */}
        <div className={classes.second_card}>
          {testimonialContent[i+1]}
        </div>
      </div>
    </Carousel.Item>
```